# js распарсить url

Tags: javascript, массивы, url, site, parse

есть  url
https://momo.org/portfolio/vnedrenie-crm/filter/crm_project_type-is-amocrm/apply/ и https://momo.org/portfolio/vnedrenie-crm/?PAGEN_1=2 и https://momo.org/portfolio/website/filter/project_type-is-korporativnyy_sayt/apply/

нужно в массив записать (JS):
Тип страницы (type) - index, filter, project, nextPage
Направление работы (direct) - website, crm
Параметры фильтра (filterParam) - строка между filter и apply
Проект (project) - код проекта из url

подскажите как этого добиться

Comment: С помощью функции URL или с помощью regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам пример: Разбиваете регулярками и вытаскиваете нужную инфу

```js
const url = 'https://momo.org/portfolio/vnedrenie-crm/filter/crm_project_type-is-amocrm/apply/';

let arr = url.replace('https://momo.org/','').match(/[^\/]{1,}\//g).map(i => i.replace('/',''));

console.log(arr);
```